# How to phrase 'has not' in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a page in our app there is a certain number of customers that are generated in a list when the page is loaded.  As one scrolls down on this page more customers are generated towards the bottom of the list, and so forth till one scrolls all the way down and there are no more customers to generate.

I am trying to check, within an .on() function, if the new generated customers at the bottom has a clock icon, and if not then to add a clock icon to the new customers.  This is my check:

```
    var isClock = $(timepickers).parent().has('.clockIcon').length ? '' : addClock;
    if (typeof isClock === 'function') {
        isClock();
    }
```

The problem is that the customers that were originally there to start with on the page, of course have the clock icon, so because some of the customers have a clock icon its not adding it to any of the ones that don't have one now.  The .has() makes more since, but I like the idea of the .is() because of what it says on the jquery website:

**Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true IF AT LEAST ONE of these elements matches the given arguments.**

And thats what I needed for it to check if ANY of the customers don't have the clock icon then to add it.  I cannot think of way to use the .is() so instead I am thinking to use the .not() or not: to see if any of the customers don't have the clock icon then run the function.  But I am not sure how to say 'if something does not have something' not 'if something is not something'.  Anyone know how to do this????

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the concept "not all".

Comment: I googled 'jquery not all' but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Is this a well known concept? How is it implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not()` instead of `has()`

Comment: this ended up working for me!

$(timepickers).parent().not(':has(.clockIcon)').append(timepickerMarkup);

Comment: You should be able to improve it slightly to `.not(".clockIcon")`

Answer (score 1):

Just negate the expression?

```
var isClock = ( ! $(timepickers).parent().has('.clockIcon').length ) ) ? '' : addClock;
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing i thought of, was http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

```
$(timepickers).parent().find('class=~"clockIcon"').length ? '' : addClock;
```

but it might not even be the simplest for your case

Answer (score 0):

See jQuery [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/). Also use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) that way you can go over each item's parent and check it individually:

```
$(timepickers).each(function () {
    // If the parent doesn't have clockIcon then add it
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('clockIcon')) {
        addClock();
    }
});
```

Comment: The parent will not have the class .clockIcon added to it, it will have a div with the class .clockIcon appended to it when the page loads. Its the customers that are generated after the page loads that is the problem.

Comment: @Tanya I have updated the answer to fit what you're asking for. Maybe you should post the HTML of what the parent will look like when it has a clockIcon and when it doesn't. That would help us out in answering you.

Answer (score 0):

While not too pretty (I don't know jQuery) this would fire the event if the elements with the icon doesn't equal the total amount of elements

```
var isClock = $(timepickers).parent().has('.clockIcon').length == $(timepickers).length ?  "" : addClock;
    if (typeof isClock === 'function') {
        isClock();
     }
```

That being said, I'm sure there is a concise way to do this with proper jQuery